# Excel find cells that partially contain a number

Tags: excel, function, search, excel-formula

I Would like to return a value if a cell partially contains a number:

**Example**:

```
Range:
A1 = 90003 B

Search value:
B1 = 90003

Return: (This is what I want)
C1 = Yes
```

I have tried something like

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,B1)), "Yes", "No")
```

But this only works for text value and not for numbers.

Please assist if you know what I can use?
I would preferably like to use a function. 
I normally just write a macro, but for this activity I would like to use a function if possible.

Comment: @Ralph - TEXT is the correct worksheet function to convert a number to formatted text. Format is the VBA command equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

To get your formula working for the supplied sample data use,

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(B1, A1)), "Yes", "No")
```

If is an either/or situation then,

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(A1, B1)), ISNUMBER(FIND(B1, A1))), "Yes", "No")
```

FIND is case-sensitive, SEARCH is not. Numbers do not have case.